# Instantiated Object is different from the output of the console. (C# UNITY)

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

[image]

As you can see on the image above on the console the first 3 output is `BLUE` but the first five on my instantiated prefab is different

[image]

It's all `BLUE` prefab.

Here's my code so far :

```
for(int col = 0; col < table.GetLength(0); col++){

        GameObject p = Instantiate(prefab_bigeye_gameobject) as GameObject;
        p.transform.SetParent (pos_big_eye_road);
        p.transform.localScale = Vector3.one;

        img = (RawImage)p.GetComponent<RawImage> ();
        for(int row = 0; row < table.GetLength(1); row++){
            if(table[moveCol, moveRow] == null){
                col0 = table[colIndex1, row];
                col1 = table[colIndex2, row];

                if(col0 != null)
                {
                    sum1+=1;
                }

                if(col1 != null)
                {
                    sum2+=1;
                }
                counter++;
            }
            else
            {
                if(counter == 0){
                    data1 = table[firstTableCol,firstTableRow];
                    data2 = table[secondTableCol,secondTableRow];
                    data3 = table[thirdTableCol,thirdTableRow];
                    data4 = table[fourthTableCol,fourthTableRow];
                }
                else{

                    if(moveRow > 1){
                        firstTableRow++;
                        secondTableRow++;
                        thirdTableRow++;
                        fourthTableRow++;
                    }else{
                        firstTableCol++;
                        secondTableCol++;
                        thirdTableCol++;
                        fourthTableCol++;
                    }
                    data1 = table[firstTableCol,firstTableRow];
                    data2 = table[secondTableCol,secondTableRow];
                    data3 = table[thirdTableCol,thirdTableRow];
                    data4 = table[fourthTableCol,fourthTableRow];

                }
                if(data1 != null && data2 != null && data3 != null && data4 != null)
                {

                    img.texture = NewTexture[1];
                    p.SetActive(true);
                    redcounter++;
                    print("RED ARE NOW AT:" + redcounter);
                }
                else
                {
                    img.texture = NewTexture[0];
                    p.SetActive(true);
                    bluecounter++;
                    print("BLUE ARE NOW AT:" + bluecounter);
                }

                if(moveRow + 1 < table.GetLength(1)){
                    moveRow++;
                }
            }
        }

        if(sum1 == sum2)
        {
            img.texture = NewTexture[1];
            p.SetActive(true);
            redcounter++;
            print("RED ARE NOW AT:" + redcounter);
        }
        else
        {
            img.texture = NewTexture[0];
            p.SetActive(true);
            bluecounter++;
            print("BLUE ARE NOW AT:" + bluecounter);
        }
        //reset
        sum1 = 0;
        sum2 = 0;

        if(colIndex1 + 1 < table.GetLength(0) && colIndex2 + 1 < table.GetLength(0))
        {
            colIndex1++;
            colIndex2++;
        }
        else
        {
            //nothing to do
        }

        if(moveCol + 1 < table.GetLength(0))
        {
            moveCol+=1;
        }
        if(moveRow + 1 < table.GetLength(1)){
            moveRow = 1;
        }
    }
```

The expected output must be

`BLUE , BLUE , BLUE, RED, BLUE`

But on my output it is

`BLUE, BLUE , BLUE, BLUE, BLUE`

Comment: the order that those objects are shown in the editor isnt necessarily the same order that they were instantiated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why instantiating it directly inside a for loop makes it crazy so what i did is separate them by creating a function

```
void blueBead(){
    p = Instantiate(prefab_bigeye_gameobject) as GameObject;
    p.transform.SetParent (pos_big_eye_road);
    p.transform.localScale = Vector3.one;

    img2 = (RawImage)p.GetComponent<RawImage>();

    img2.texture = NewTexture[0];
    p.SetActive(true);
}

void redBead(){
    p = Instantiate(prefab_bigeye_gameobject) as GameObject;
    p.transform.SetParent (pos_big_eye_road);
    p.transform.localScale = Vector3.one;

    img2 = (RawImage)p.GetComponent<RawImage>();

    img2.texture = NewTexture[1];
    p.SetActive(true);
}
```

and call them like this

```
if(data1 != null && data2 != null && data3 != null && data4 != null)
{

    readBead();
}
else
{
    blueBead();
}
```